# Class literal from a class object based on an interface

Tags: java, generics

At first look it doesn't look like this might be possible so it would be good to hear some design patterns or a work around to make this work.

I need to provide an external library with the class literal `Class<T>` in order for it to find the right type and annotations and pull from dynamodb. Here is the signature

```
public <T> T load(java.lang.Class<T> clazz, java.lang.Object hashKey)
```

However in my application needed class type is dynamic and gets resolved dynamically from the interface.

Here is an example where I resolve the class's full name dynamically from an interface.

```
String dynamoDBTypeName = getDynamoDBClassName(someInterface);
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(dynamoDBTypeName);
```

and then I need convert clazz to class literal so it can be passed to

```
mapper.load(SomeClazz.class, hashKey)
```

I couldn't find a solution on how to convert a class object to a class literal so I can pass the actual type to the lib. Is there such one? Or is there a more elegant solution of dynamically resolving an interface to the class literal?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by converting a class object to a class literal. A class literal is something like `String.class`. If you obtain that object by doing `Class.forName` what does it mean to convert it to a literal?

Comment: by class object I mean Class<?> and class literal is a Class<T>

Comment: Oh I see. In that case you can't do it without an unchecked cast. `Class<Whatever> clazz = (Class<Whatever>) Class.forName(...)`.

Comment: thanks @PaulBoddington could you think of a workaround? The kinda dirty one I can think is to use a switch statement to map an interface to the class literals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your intent correctly, then you can just do this:

```
String dynamoDBTypeName = getDynamoDBClassName(someInterface);
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(dynamoDBTypeName);
Object loaded = mapper.load(clazz, hashKey);
```

Whether you get the class from Someclass.class or Class.forName(...), it's the same class object.  The values of type parameters are only defined at compile time, so there is absolutely no difference in the information passed to mapper.load, the code that implements mapper.load, or the value that it returns.

The only difference is that if you pass a `Class<X>` to mapper.load() then the compiler knows that it will return an X and you can assign it to a variable of type X without casting.  If you pass a `Class<?>` the compiler only knows that it will return an Object.  It can be cast to an instance of the class by some code that knows what type it's supposed to be.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change return type of the  mapper.load is a part of the external SDK. So this signature must be followed `public <T> T load(java.lang.Class<T> clazz, java.lang.Object hashKey)`

Comment: I didn't change the return type.  When you pass in a Class<?>, the return type is ?.  The compiler knows its a subsclass of Object, so you can assign it to an Object no problem.

Comment: There is something wrong with the way you are thinking about Java generics, but I can't quite put my finger on it.  Remember that these type parameters like T don't change anything about the code that actually runs.  They just help the compiler check your work.

Comment: That might work actually, I think the mistake that I made is that I was trying to assign mapper.load result to the type T rather than an object  `T result = mapper.load(clazz, hashKey)`